# Controller does not receive data from custom htmlHelper in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating custom `HtmlHelper(checkbox)` in **ASP.NET MVC4**. But the controller does not receive the data from that custom control when I submit the form.

My code for custom control:

```
/* Extension Checkbox */
    public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxExtension<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string className)
    {
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

        TagBuilder checkbox = new TagBuilder("input");
        if (metaData.SimpleDisplayText != null)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(metaData.SimpleDisplayText))
            {
                checkbox.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");
            }
        }
        checkbox.MergeAttribute("id", metaData.PropertyName);
        checkbox.MergeAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        checkbox.MergeAttribute("class", className);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(checkbox.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting checkbox value in controller because you haven't added `name` attribute in checkbox. Try to Add name attribute like following

```
var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText((LambdaExpression)expression);
checkbox.Attributes.Add("name", name);
```

Comment: i try add attribute [name], variable [FormCollection] catched data, but Model are not getting data :(

Comment: `
/* Attribute */
        public Fly_PositionGallery PositionGalleries { get; set; }
        public Fly_Video Video { get; set; }
        public Fly_SectionContent SectionContents { get; set; }

        public List<Fly_PositionGallery> ListPositionGalleries;
        public List<Fly_Video> ListVideo;
        public List<Fly_SectionContent> ListSectionContents;
     

        /* DataAccess */
        PositionGalleryDAO posGallery;
        VideosDAO sectionVideo; 
`

Comment: Checkbox always return Boolean value and i don't see any boolean property in your model

Answer (score 0):

The `@Html.CheckBoxFor` will create two inputs, one is a checkbox, the other is hidden. In the hidden input, the value is false, and the checkbox value is true. They have the same name. When you post, if the checkbox is checked, the post value is (true,false). If the checkbox is unchecked, the post value is only false, so the binder will bind the value to a boolean property; if the post value has true, bool is set to true.
So I think you should add a hidden input for the unchecked case. Just like `@Html.CheckBoxFor`.